# Keyboard keys miswired since dual boot of Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, 18.04

Ever since I dual booted Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04, some of my keyboard keys are miswired.

For example, pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+number row <kbd>2</kbd> gives a `"` (instead of `@`)

How to fix this?

I am using an [HP laptop](https://www.amazon.in/HP-14q-BU007TU-Lightweight-Integrated-Graphics/dp/B0751BZ84M/ref=sr_1_15?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1533320625&sr=1-15&refinements=p_n_feature_browse-bin%3A1464451031%2Cp_89%3AHP).

Comment: Probably wrong keyboard mapping. This only happens on Ubuntu or does this happens in Windows also?

Comment: @Bernard only Ubuntu.

Comment: Check the keyboard configuration in Windows, you can then select the same type of keyboard under Ubuntu Settings->Regions & Language to see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the photos on the website you purchased from, it looks very much to me that you have the US keyboard set as the <kbd>"</kbd> key and <kbd>@</kbd> are reversed whereas the photo clearly shows you have the English keyboard layout...

[image]

The above image is of the US keyboard layout and below the British (English)

[image]

So, In windows you have the correct keyboard mapping set but the incorrect one in Ubuntu.

You should change which keyboard layout you are using in Ubuntu System Settings>Regions & Language.

Comment: I had to set Language to English (United Kingdom) and Formats to India. And Input Sources to English (India, with rupee).

Comment: Well done! Have an upvote with my compliments.